# Listing all Lattice Points in a Box

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming, enumerative-geometry, euclidean-lattices

Let $B := [-1,1]^n$ be an $n$-dimensional box. Moreover, let $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where the entries of the $v_i$ are explicitly irrational. We can assume that $\mathrm{det}(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = 1$.

Then,
 $$L := \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n v_i k_i, \text{ where } (k_1,\ldots,k_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n \right\} $$
is a lattice.

I am interested in enumerating (not just counting) all the points in $L \cap B$ for $n$ up to dimension 12. Is this possible at all?
Which algorithms are suited for this problem?

Comment: Take suitable rational approximations and use BKZ (or LLL), then generate points and test them until you are guaranteed to be outside the box.

Comment: The rational approximation should do the trick. Then you can trianguliarize your basis with Hermite Normal Form and backtrack the coordinate of the points.